# Email is not send after submit on form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have problem with sending email from *html* form. Somehow when i click *submit* nothing happens. The validation of *fields* works nevertheless as mentioned before nothing happens when doing submit button. What could be wrong here?

**html part:**

```
<section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Formularz kontaktowy</h3>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                <form role="form" id="contactForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"
                                placeholder="Wpisz swoje imię, nazwisko" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"
                                required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5"
                                placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn-block">Wyślij wiadomość</button>
                        <div class="alert alert-success h4 hidden" id="msgSubmit">
                            <strong>Udało się!</strong> Twoja wiadomość została wysłana poprawnie.
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger h4 hidden" id="msgError">
                            <strong>Błąd</strong> Prosimy odświeżyć stronę i spróbować ponownie.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Scripts:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contactForm").on("submit", function (event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });
});
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
        success: function (text) {
            if (text == "success") {
                $("#msgSubmit").removeClass("hidden");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#msgSubmit").addClass("hidden");
                }, 6000);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            /* You probably want to add an error message as well */
            $("#msgError").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

**mail.php file:**

```
<?php
//Required field names array
$required = array('name', 'email', 'message');

//Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $error = true;
  }
}

if ($error) 
{
   echo "invalid";  //Was empty values should not be reached as html form inspecting it as well
} else {   
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $EmailTo = "name@myemailxx.com";
    $Subject = $name;

    $message .= "\n\n" . 'From: '. $email;
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message);

    //Results catched by AJAX
    if ($success){
        echo "success";
    }else
    {
        echo "invalid";
    }    
}
?>
```

**When going into console i see such errors ut do not know how to fix it?:**

```
(index):32 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):32:9

(index):44 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):44:9
```

**For both is says:**

```
Uncatcuch reefereencee error. $
```

**and error is highlited over those lines:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var owl = $("#owl-hero");
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#contactForm").on("submit", function (event) {
```

**besides on the top level tag: 
i see that error:**

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.xxx.com.pl/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: There is a problem with your mail.php file. Go to inspect and see the network tab to see what error is showing while submitting the form.

Comment: And you can always check you browser console for any front-end related errors

Comment: @ChiragAshara if it'smail.php related issue why then i do not see thee message comming from that part of code?: `<div class="alert alert-danger h4 hidden" id="msgError">
                            <strong>Błąd</strong> Prosimy odświeżyć stronę i spróbować ponownie.
                        </div>`

Comment: Note that you don't do anything at all when the AJAX was successful and when something other than `"success"` was returned. However, it is also possible that your code did sent the email, but you regard, not receiving an email, as "nothing happening". It is certainly possible an email gets sent but never arrives in the destination mailbox. There's an easy test: Just use the PHP `mail()` function on it's own and see if you get the email.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i went into console and see some errors which i added to the main post, can u help me to fix them? I am not good in front end.

Comment: DId you include [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) in your web page? This library is needed by your Javascript.

Comment: The last error tells you that since your site is using `https`, all external assets (like jQuery) must then be loaded using `https`. Since you're currently trying to load jQuery using `http`, the browser blocks it for being insecure and it isn't included in your site. Fix for that error: use `https://...` when loading external resources, like jQuery.